# Dynamic Vertexbuffer in SharpDX

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, sharpdx, vertex-buffer

I have massive Problems figuring out how to set up a dynamic VertexBuffer and IndexBuffer using SharpDX.

I have to generate Triangles where ever the User presses on the Screen.

I think i have to set up a transformation function that converts my screen coordinates to projection coordinates.

But i dont ever come this far...

I want to set up a Buffer with space for 10000 Vertices.

```
layout = new InputLayout(d3dDevice, vertexShaderByteCode, new[]
{
    new SharpDX.Direct3D11.InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
    new SharpDX.Direct3D11.InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16, 0)
});

vb = Buffer.Create(d3dDevice, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, stream, 10000, ResourceUsage.Dynamic, CpuAccessFlags.Write);

vertexBufferBinding = new VertexBufferBinding(vb, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() * 2, 0);
```

That Buffer i want to update every time i have to add new triangles using:

```
d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.UpdateSubresource(updateVB, vb);
```

updateVB are the new Triangles to be added.

Rendering works the following way:

```
// Prepare matrices
var view = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, -5), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
var proj = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4.0f, width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(view, proj);

// Set targets (This is mandatory in the loop)
d3dContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(render.DepthStencilView, render.RenderTargetView);

// Clear the views
d3dContext.ClearDepthStencilView(render.DepthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);

d3dContext.ClearRenderTargetView(render.RenderTargetView, Colors.Black);

// Calculate WorldViewProj
var worldViewProj = Matrix.Scaling(1f) * viewProj;
worldViewProj.Transpose();

// Setup the pipeline
d3dContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, vertexBufferBinding);
d3dContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
d3dContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;

d3dContext.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
d3dContext.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);

d3dContext.Draw(vertexCount, 0);
```

I am new to DirectX and the DirectX9 tutorials on the web don't help me very good with DirectX11.1.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, some contents looks stolen by this site:
http://ask.programmershare.com/1190_12051844/;jsessionid=8C0F732447C497F1578FEC3A013771CE

Answer (score 1):

```
vb = Buffer.Create(d3dDevice, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, stream, 10000, ResourceUsage.Dynamic, CpuAccessFlags.Write);
```

Is wrong, since you want 10000 vertices, but allocate 10000 bytes, so should be:

```
 10000 * sizeof(Vector4) * 2
```

According to your input layout.

Also to write into your buffer, you should look at context.MapSubresource instead.